# Big-O notation of this code is o(logn) ?? or o(n^1/2)?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
void func (int n)
{
     int i = 1, s = 1;
     while ( s < n ) {
           s = s + i++;
           printf("*");
     }
}
```

I think this code is f(n) = O(log(n)), but my friend said this is O(n^1/2). I’m so confused

Link to picture with original code -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBOh.png

Comment: that is `O(n^1/2)`, but sum of arithmetic progression can be calculated in `O(1)`

Comment: Please post code as text, not images of code.

Comment: Why do you think it's log(n)?  Nothing exponentially increases `s` each loop iteration.  Thanks for editing to replace the image of text, but `i * (i+1) / 2` growth of `sum += i++` is well known.  This question might be better suited to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ because your confusion is purely about theoretical complexity analysis.  Although you can just run it and look at how many `*` characters it outputs, so that's handy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you missed that it's `while ( s < n )`. What you say, the sum of the first `i` numbers, requires `while ( i <= n )` (and to be precise, `s` should start from 0). This is very different. Although I can't answer, I can see why the OP thinks it's logarithmic. [See it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/kEFl1d).

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica: I didn't miss that.  The time (number of steps for `s` to reach `n`) is the inverse function of how `s` grows with `i`.  So log(n) time could only happen with exponential growth of `s`, not any polynomial like you'd get from adding incremented `i`.  I'm not saying it's *obvious* that `s` grows as a quadratic function of `i` or even that it's obvious that it's not log, I'm literally just asking why the OP specifically came to that conclusion, to find out what misconception they're having.  And encouraging them to put more of their thought process into words.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I see what you mean now, and I think you are right. Sorry, and thanks for the explanation!